# Checking Definitions for Self-Consistency and Cycles

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, dictionary

I am building a "self-contained" set of definitions, and would like to ensure that the definitions:

1. Do not contain circular definitions (which might include other words within that cycle, not just a direct cycle)
2. Are properly ordered (definitions requiring a word show up after that word has already been defined)

How can I detect cycles, and also determine the ordering of the defintions?

I would assume that dictionaries already employ some kind of tool(s) to accomplish this, but have been unable to find anything. Suggestions on how these things might be accomplished?

Comment: You are essentially asking for two graph algorithms - this is not specific to linguistics. Try [cs.se] if you want to understand the algorithm itself. If you're looking for tools that do this I'm not sure how to help you.

Comment: Surely if a word is defined in terms of other words, the definition will always turn out to be circular within some cycle. Also, dictionaries aren't really ordered, are they? I mean I know the definitions are alphabetical, but there's no expectation that users will read them in that order - it's just done so you can find your way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keelan points out, the properties you're looking for can be provided by [cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) and [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) algorithms, respectively.

As an aside: I don't know of any dictionary that tries to ensure either property. It is generally not seen as an issue by lexicographers if definitions are circular. The closest thing I've seen is [a toy dictionary made for English](https://academic.oup.com/ijl/article-abstract/24/2/226/952719?redirectedFrom=fulltext) using the [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage) developed by semanticists.

Comment: Not a dictionary of course, but Wittgenstein's *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus* comes to mind as another example of a text in which ordering has been taken beyond usefulness.